# Visual Studio IDE Helper/Summary - Reference name of passed object through constructor

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, attributes

I have an example script below, something that is generic as to avoid creating many classes that only ever store two properties. However when working with multiple instances, all the .x .y etc references get a bit harder to track. Especially when re-visiting a project.

I am wondering if it is possible to add some kind of helper in the IDE. Something that will add a summary when hovering over one of the variable fields, which references the name of the object that was passed through the public constructor.

For example, if instantiating Example(id, someObject). When typing object dot 'x', there will be a summary with the name 'ID'. And 'someObject' with dot 'y'.

```
class Example<X, Y>
{
    public X x;
    public Y y;

    public Example(X x, Y y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Is something like this possible?
Or is it just general bad practice to create generic style objects?

Thank you in advance :)

### ****EDIT**

In reply to current feedback, I am relatively familiar with most of the /// summary attributes available.

But I was going for something like this. Which I don't think is achievable. But thought it best to ask just in case.

[image]

Comment: "no" is the short answer (the code only receives the value of the expression after evaluation; not how it got there - except maybe "expression trees", but seriously: don't go there for this); "maybe kinda value-tuples" is a slightly longer one, but they have significant limitations

Comment: Are you for comments that will be shown whenever you use the object?  Something like  `/// <summary>
        /// My method does something.
        /// </summary>`

Comment: Enter `///` above your object or method and VS will insert comments you can populate.

Comment: You can try ReSharper or Visual Assist.

Answer (score 0):

```
/// <summary>
/// My Class.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="X"></typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="Y"></typeparam>
class Example<X, Y>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// My Var 1
    /// </summary>
    public X x;

    /// <summary>
    /// My Var 2
    /// </summary>
    public Y y;

    /// <summary>
    /// My Example.  This will be displayed anytime you hover over where the example is called.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="x">My first param.</param>
    /// <param name="y">My second param.</param>
    /// <remarks>Some extra into.</remarks>
    /// <example>This is how you use it.</example>
    public Example(X x, Y y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Whenever you use any of those elements, you can mouse over the name and the comment text will appear.

Just start typing `///` above any class, variable, or method and the comments will be auto-generated.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/generate-xml-documentation-comments?view=vs-2019